# How to fix "pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: -n"

Tags: pytest, pytest-xdist

Hi I am trying to run my tests parallely(pytest-xdist) on the azure pipelines.
Till now the tests were running perfectly fine.
Suddenly the pytest is throwing a weird error saying "unrecognized argument".

The file name : integration_test.py
Command used : pytest -n 5 --tb=short integration_test.py -v -s  --> to run 5 tests parallely
Total number of tests : 57
Versions :
pytest==6.2.5
pytest-xdist==2.3.0
Even tried with the latest versions of these 2 modules.

Error :
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: -n integration_test.py

How can I overcome this error?

Comment: You haven‘t installed `pytest-xdist` which adds the `-n` argument.

Comment: I have installed the pytest-xdist module.

Comment: Still facing the issue

Comment: Then you probably haven't installed it for the right interpreter. Run `pytest -v --collect-only`, is `xdist` listed in plugins? Best add the output to the question.

Answer (score 11):

This error is what you encountered:

```
Error : ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...] pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: -n integration_test.py  
  initfile: None
  rootdir: C:\test
```

[image]

As hoefling mentioned, the solution is to install the pytest-xdist:

`pip install pytest-xdist`

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS just running `pytest` might be ran by a different Python's version than you thought.

```
$ pytest
============================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.12, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: [REDACTED]
plugins: anyio-3.5.0, cov-3.0.0
```

While

```
$ python3 -m pytest
============================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: [REDACTED]
plugins: xdist-2.5.0, forked-1.4.0, pylama-8.4.1
```

Be careful, and launch it as a module :)